# Is it safe to access a for loop counter after the loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope

Is this ok?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   ...
}
doSomething(i);
```

Obviously I expect `i` to have the value 10 here. My testing indicates it's ok, but is this defined behaviour? (ES5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is defined behavior. The current version of JavaScript doesn't have block scoping, there is only function scope.

However, the new standard of JavaScript (ES6) is introducing a `let` statement (an alternative to `var`), which will respect block scope.

In the following code, you would not be able to access `i` outside of the loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is really a question of scope. Do you want i to be accessible outside the for loop?</strike>

<strike>If so, and you want to make sure, define i outside the loop. Something like:</strike>

Duh... Variables in `for` loops aren't blocked (barring the `let` option in ES6). Which I already knew, but I'm tired and spaced it. So of course `i` will be accessible, and defining it outside the `for` loop is entirely unnecessary.

I'm going to leave this up as a reminder to myself not to jump the gun when I'm tired and haven't fully thought through my answer.

```
var i;
for(i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
...
}
doSomething(i);
```

<strike>**Edit**: After double-checking, i is definitely going to be accessible no matter what, and that is defined behavior, so it's safe either way.</strike>

Comment: This answer is not accurate. What's going on here is that a `var` gets hoisted and it doesn't get affected by block scoping.

Comment: You're right, of course. Leaving it up anyway, with edits, to remind myself not to pull the answer trigger too fast when I'm over tired and haven't thought it through.